# Update table from another table by id and select

Tags: mysql

We have 2 tables

**Titles**

```
+------+--------------- ----+---------------------+---------------------+
| id   | title              | subs_updated        | created_at          |
+------+--------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
|  104 | movie 1            | 2014-11-13 05:40:51 | 2014-11-11 12:08:28 |
|  129 | movie 2            |                     | 2014-11-11 12:08:29 |
+------+--------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

**Subs**

```
+----+----------+----------+---------+---------------------+
| id |  label   | title_id | subs    | created_at          |
+----+----------+----------+---------+---------------------+
| 13 | English  |      104 | English | 2014-11-12 05:05:39 |
| 15 | Italian  |      104 | Italian | 2014-11-12 05:25:00 |
| 16 | Dutch    |      104 | Dutch   | 2014-11-13 05:40:51 |
| 18 | Arabic   |      129 | Arabic  | 2014-11-12 06:05:28 |
| 19 | Arabic   |      129 | Arabic  | 2014-11-12 06:07:23 |
+----+----------+----------+---------+---------------------+
```

1. I want to find the last created sub for an id in subs table.
2. Update the subs_updated column by ID in titles table.

Please some help

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
   UPDATE 
  `title` 
SET
  subs_updated = 
  (SELECT 
    created_at
  FROM
    `subs`  
  WHERE subs.title_id = title.id ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 1)
```